# HTML form textarea problem

Tags: html, forms, authentication, webforms

In my html form the word message is showing at the bottom-left of the textarea, How can I adjust it on the top-left of textarea? img - http://img641.imageshack.us/img641/415/htms.jpg

```
      <form name="reg_form" method="post" action="home.php">
                First Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
         <input type="text" name="f_name"/><br/>  <br/>  
                Last Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <input type="text" name="l_name"/><br/> <br/>
                Your Email:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type="text" name="new_email"/><br/> <br/>
                Re-enter Email:&nbsp;<input type="text" name="check_email"/><br/> <br/>
                Message:&nbsp;<textarea cols="30" rows="10" name="message"></textarea>
         </form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use a `<label>` tag to put your, well, labels in. Then using some CSS you can align it to the top of the `<textarea>` using this:

```
label
{
    display: inline;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

HTML:

```
<form>
    <label>Message:</label>
    <textarea></textarea>
</form>
```

There's a live example I made [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jamwaffles/e64nV/).

### In other news

Your technique of spacing the inputs using `&nbsp;` isn't the best. For one, different fonts have different space widths and secondly, it makes your code look rubbish. You can get around this by using `<label>`s with CSS `inline-block`. There's a working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jamwaffles/HrvgB/).